# Sqoop incremental import from postgres to HDFS is giving org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import incremental data from postgres sql to hdfs's directory using sqoop job as,

```
sqoop job --create incident_import -- import --connect jdbc:postgresql://IP ADDRESS:5432/Analyst_Bangalore --username postgres  --password track@123 --map-column-java the_geom=String   --table incident -m 1  --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/analyst_bangalore.db --incremental lastmodified --check-column incident_start_time --last-value "2016-08-03 14:33:48.087"   --driver org.postgresql.Driver  -- --schema analyst
```

If I am executing this job it's giving ERROR as,

```
sqoop job -exec incident_import

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "incident" does not exist
  Position: 17
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:758)

2016-11-14 18:35:47,255 ERROR tool.ImportTool (ImportTool.java:run(613)) - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
```

anybody have any idea please share me.It is a littlebit required.

Comment: Does `incident` table exists in database ?

Comment: yes,i have.Already i imported data from that table into hdfs.

Comment: is this working for you ? `sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/analyst --username postgres  --password track@123 --map-column-java the_geom=String   --table incident -m 1  --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/analyst_bangalore.db --incremental lastmodified --check-column incident_start_time --last-value "2016-08-03 14:33:48.087"   --driver org.postgresql.Driver`

Comment: no that is also giving same error.I am not able to find the cause.But only import is working.Now also i tried with some other directory.sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.130:5432/Analyst_Bangalore --username postgres --password track@123 --table incident --map-column-java the_geom=String  -m 1 --warehouse-dir /user/hdfs -- --schema analyst

Comment: here use `--connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.130:5432/`. don't add `Analyst_Bangalore `

Comment: thank you for reply.I tried ,then also it is giving same error.

Comment: anybody hava any idea please share me.